# Is it preferable to use "this" or "that" (where var that = this)?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm cleaning up some JavaScript code I downloaded. One of the inconsistencies in this code is mixed usage of both `this` and the local variable `that` that references it.

An example code snippet (private method within a jQuery UI widget):

```
_populateLists: function(options) {
    //do stuff with this

    var that = this;
    options.each(function(index) {
        //use both this AND that, they are different in this scope
    });

    //here this and that are the same thing
    //I want to be consistent, is one preferable over the other?
},
```

In many places throughout the code, where the scope is such that `this === that`,  there is mixed usage, even within the same line of code.

For the sake of readability and maintainability, is it preferable to use `this` or `that`?

Note: I realize a lot of these types of things depend on developer preference. But before I decide to rewrite the code to use one over the other, I'd like to understand any reasoning if/why one would be preferred over the other.

**EDIT:** In this script, I think the *only* reason `this` is being assigned to a local variable is so that it can be referred to from within the inner closure.

Comment: "For the sake of .." I use `this` *except* when `that` (which I call something else) is needed to achieve the correct semantics. Thus, `that` (which I call something else) is used as sentinel/note in my code and should not be used in context where `this` is desired.

Comment: `that` is a horrible name for a variable (and I'm very much guilty of using it). `this` I would call debatable since in some situations it conveys the purpose of the variable right away, for example, when looping over a collection, and using `this` to refer to each item in the collection. If `this` is causing any confusion, give it a meaningful name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the value of `this` is commonly assigned to a local variable is so that you can close over that value and use it inside a nested function.

`this` is a special variable and somewhat different from normal local variables in that it is automatically set to the object upon which a function was called (if any); otherwise, the global object.  However, this intrinsic value of `this` is somewhat muddied by jQuery's liberal use of [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which allow the caller to *specify* the value of `this`.

In a nested function, `this` does not inherit the value of its parent's `this` in the same way it would inherit a parent's local variables through the scope chain.

Because of this, we have to stash the value of `this` in a local variable if we need it inside a nested function, such as the `each` callback in your example.

```
var a = { fn: function() {
    // here, `this` is the object `a`
    var x = this;
    function b() {
        // here, `this` is `window` because `b` is invoked with no context
        // ...but we still have access to `x`, whose value would be `a`
    }
    b();
}};

a.fn(); // by invoking `fn` as a property of `a`, we implicitly set `fn`'s
        // `this` to `a`.

// Compare to:
var f = a.fn;
f();    // we now invoke `fn` with no context, so its `this` will be `window`.
a.fn.call(window); // or by specifying context explicitly
```

Of course, when you're still in the parent scope, `this` will still equal `that` (or `self` or whatever).  At first glance, it may seem like there's no difference between the two, but there is one important performance impact:

**Minification.**  If you assign `this` to a local variable, all references to that variable can be reduced to one character.  References to `this` cannot.  Compare this minified output:

```
function a() {this.w=1;this.x=2;this.y=3;this.z=4;}
function b() {var t=this;t.w=1;t.x=2;t.y=3;t.z=4;}
```

With 4 references to `this`, you save bytes by using a variable.  If you have to capture `this` for an inner function anyway, using the local variable instead of `this` in the outer function gets you savings even with a single reference.

Comment: +1 for understanding the purpose of assigning `this` to a local variable in the example scenario and for giving a non-subjective reason why one might prefer to use the local variable.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any reason, other than the standard subjective rationales of consistency and meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the trouble of assigning `this` to a local variable, it's probably a good idea to use it, especially if you've given the local variable a useful name:

```
$('body').on('click', '.something', function() {
  var clicked = this;

  // now "clicked" is the element clicked on
});
```

for a jQuery example, but it's the same issue regardless of library or in raw JavaScript.  Personally I think "that" is a pretty weak variable name in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of assigning `this` to a local variable is to achieve semantics, then it would make sense to use a semantic variable name and then use the variable rather than `this`.

But since the purpose of assigning `this` to a local variable in this scenario is to cache it for use in an inner function, I think it's more readable/semantic to continue to use `this` in the outer scope.

While `that` is not normally a very good variable name, I think the meaning remains clear in this scenario. In my mind, in the inner scope, *that* is to *this* as *parent* is to *self*.

And since this is a jQuery UI widget, I looked at the source of some of the standard widgets that 'ship' with jQuery UI. It seems to be a standard convention to use `this` throughout except when needing to refer to the `this` of the outer scope. In the latter case, `this` is cached in a variable named `that`. Even when the local variable exists, it's only used in the inner scope.

**Example for clarity:**

```
_populateLists: function(options) {
    var that = this; //we'll need `this` within a closure later

    //do some stuff with `this`

    options.each(function(index) {
        //do stuff with `this` AND `that`
        //`that` is the `this` of the outer scope
    });

    //do some more stuff with `this`
},
```

If consistency is the goal, then it makes sense to follow the same convention used by standard jQuery UI widgets.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a variable to `$(this)` when using jQuery, it is preferable to use `$this` as it refers to a jQuery object ( `$` ). It is commonly used when `$(this)` no longer refers to the parent object when in the scope of another function.

The variable name however does not matter and simply refers to the object assigned. We could use `$this`, `$that`, `$obj`, `that`, `obj`, `button` etc. as our variable name, however `this` in javascript is a reserved word referring to the object in the current scope so we cannot use `this` as the variable name. You cannot assign any type of value to `this` or `$(this)`.

Example...

```
this = 'something'; // or
$(this) = 'something';
```

Both of the above statements will throw an exception.

An example using `$this = $(this);` is shown below

**To change the html of a button with the id of "someButton" after a successful jQuery post...**

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    var data = $('form').serializeArray();
    // some validation or something

    $this = $(this);
    // note the lack of the var command to 
    // globalize $this within the click function

    $.post('somePage',data,function(html) {
         $this.html(html); 
         // identical to $('#someButton').html(html);
    });
});
```